# Do the variables declared by `nonlocal` in these two examples both not exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following two examples, is it correct that the variables declared by `nonlocal` do not exist?

Then why is there an error in the first example, while there is no error in the second example? Thanks.

Example 1:

```
count = 0

def make_counter():
    def counter():
        nonlocal count  # SyntaxError: no binding for nonlocal 'count' found
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

Example 2:

```
a = 5

def f():
    a=2
    class C1:
        a = 3
        def f1(self):
            nonlocal a  # refers to `a` local to `f`
            a = 4
        def f2(self):
            self.f1()
            print(self.a)
    print(a)

f()  # 2
print(a)  # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Per python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement

`nonlocal` looks for the *nearest enclosing scope*. In Example 1, you have:

```
count = 0 # global scope

def make_counter():
    # nonlocal scope
    def counter():
        # nonlocal scope, count references something in the global scope
        nonlocal count
        count += 1
        return count
    return counter
```

`count` is two "scope levels" away and is also in the `global` scope, so `nonlocal` throws a syntax error since it is not in the `nonlocal` scope.

In Example 2:

```
a = 5 # global scope

def f():
    # nonlocal scope
    a=2 # "a" referenced in nonlocal scope!
    class C1:
        # nonlocal scope
        a = 3 # "a" referenced in nonlocal scope!
        def f1(self):
            # local scope
            # "a" most recently referenced in nearest enclosing scope, no syntax error!
            nonlocal a
            a = 4
        def f2(self):
            self.f1()
            print(self.a)
    print(a)

f()  # 2
print(a)  # 5
```

Since `a` in example 2 was referenced in an adjacent `nonlocal` scope, it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Example 1 doesn't fail because `count` isn't in the immediately previous scope; it fails because it isn't found in any *nonglobal* scope. From the documentation: "The `nonlocal` statement causes the listed identifiers to refer to previously bound variables in the nearest enclosing scope *excluding globals*." (emphasis mine)

Comment: in #1 it throws because `count` is in the **global** scope, not because it is two scopes away, `nonlocal` works fine for closure-in-closure-in-closure(etc. etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The example given made me thing it was one scope previous.

Comment: In example 2, in definition of method `f1`, `a` in `nonlocal a` doesn't refer to `C.a`, you need `C.a` instead of `a`